# Loading image from Assets to NSImage keep getting error, expecting NSImage.Name

Tags: swift, nsimage

I am trying to load a file from `xcassets` to an `NSImage`, where the asset name is logo.

I tried this:

```
let logoIcon = NSImage(named: "logo")
```

But I keep getting this error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'NSImage.Name'

I have looked into the Apple Dev Documentation and from what I can tell this is correct. But for some reason I keep getting the error.

I am trying to do it on macOS if that makes a difference

**EDIT:**

So I am trying to make a top menu bar app.

And I have adjust the code such that icon is loaded into `logoIcon` but the Icon is not set in the top menu bar.

```
import Cocoa

extension NSImage.Name {
    static let logo = NSImage.Name("Logo")

}


@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    @IBOutlet weak var statusMenu: NSMenu!

    let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: -1)


    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

        // statusItem.title  = "SECRET"

        let logoIcon = NSImage(named: .logo)

        // icon?.isTemplate = true
        statusItem.image = logoIcon
        statusItem.menu = statusMenu

    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    } 

}
```

Comment: Same problem here. Using the logo from assets shows a huge symbol. Using png looks like pixel hell. Did you manage to get it working?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to this answer in [Apple Developer Forums:](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/80627)

> ... seems like NSImage(named: String) has been replaced by NSImage(named: NSImage.Name) in Swift 4.

So as suggested in the answer you can create an extension of the struct NSImage.Name:

```
extension NSImage.Name {  
    static let logo = NSImage.Name("logo")  
}
```

And use it in this way:

```
let logoIcon = NSImage(named: .logo)
```

Comment: Besides the fact that the icon is not loaded, the problem is solved. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You are welcome, if you need help to load the image update your question and show what are you trying ;)

Comment: I did that :) I am trying to make a top menu bar application

Comment: Try setting your statusItem in this way: `let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.squareLength)` and `logoIcon.isTemplate = true`

Answer (score 6):

Francesco Deliro's answer is correct, and you can avoid creating an extension to NSImage.Name with:

```
let logoIcon = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name("logo"))
```

Answer (score 3):

To load from the assets catalog of the current bundle, use something like:

`let image = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).image(forResource: NSImage.Name(“logo"))!`

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for but it's pretty counterintuitive. I would never would have figured it out on my own!